# visualizing objects in 2D or 3D ( z axis = 0 )

Tags: android, opengl-es

which one is totaly better/faster considering performace 2D or 3D(z=0) ?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Significant difference between _what_ _exactly_?

Comment: OpenGL is not _really_ concerned with 2D drawing. Do you intend to use another API or why do you make the difference?

Comment: I consider using processing and open GL and my aim is designing 2D visualization right now but open GL ES seems more professional .